# Edit init-file for "dead-tilde" in emacs Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-14.04

I am having problems with dead-tilde in emacs.
So far I have used the following solution for it:

env XMODIFIERS= emacs

It works but since I really want to only type "emacs" in the terminal everytime it becomes really annoying to type the above command.

I have tried the following to the init-file in ~/.emacs:
(require 'iso-transl)

It gave no result, also tried:
(require 'iso-transl)
(load-library "iso-transl")

And only:
(load-library "iso-transl")

Obviously I am doing something wrong here, got any clue to it?

Answer (score 0):

With the following written in the init-file ~/.emacs: (load-library "iso-transl")
After editing the init-file, logout and login again from your account and then it is fixed.